# How do I get the MySQL Workbench's Messages in Bash

Tags: mysql, bash, output, mysql-workbench

I am trying to find a flag or option to see the Messages as to how many rows were changed/updated in the MySQL query from the command line(Bash).

For example: I have pasted the output row of a query from the MySQL Workbench GUI:

```
12:56:27    UPDATE `mydb`.`User` SET `Status` = 'A' WHERE (`UserID` = '65')

1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0  0.031 sec**
```

In the above example, it's easy for me to know as to how many rows were affected after the query execution. However, I am not sure how will I get the similar result from the CLI. I tried -v (verbose) flag but that does not make sense.

I need to know these messages regarding the row counts affected as I am scheduling a job for data changes.

Is there any way, I can achieve this using any default mysql flags or any other suggestions.

TIA.

Comment: Use the `mysql` shell command with the `-vvv` option to get the most verbose output.

Comment: You can [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) --  It's a little longer than one query, but it works well for selecting the rows that were affected in an update.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. The option -vvv worked as expected.